# Cannot set Azure SQL Database Long-term backup retention

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, azureportal, azure-sql-server, azure-backup-vault

I'm trying to re-configure long term backup retention for my Azure SQL Database from a previously deleted **recovery services vault** (via Powershell) to a new **recovery services vault**

Now when I try to configure it gives me an error saying

> TemplateBladeVirtualPart
>   SQLAZUREEXTENSION

Here is the script I used to removed the old recovery services vault (if it matters?)

```
$vault = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name "is-vault-prod"
Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $vault
$container = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureSQL -FriendlyName $vault.Name
$item = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $container -WorkloadType AzureSQLDatabase
$availableBackups = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint -Item $item
$containers = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureSQL -FriendlyName $vault.Name
ForEach ($container in $containers)
{
    $items = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -container $container -WorkloadType AzureSQLDatabase
    ForEach ($item in $items)
    {
        Disable-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -item $item -RemoveRecoveryPoints -ea SilentlyContinue
    }
    Unregister-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -Container $container
}
Remove-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Vault $vault
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you just cannot choose another Recovery service vault once you had already used one.

I did a test in my lab and tried to disable the long backup retention but still failed, and found that:

[image]

This screenshot means that once you configured a recovery service vault for a SQL Server, it will be locked , you cannot use another vault.

I also found this in [a FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-retention#long-term-backup-retention-faq):

> Can I register my server to store backups to more than one vault?
>
> No, you can currently store backups to only one vault at a time.

I understand why you want to use another vault.

However, We can just use this recovery service vault currently.If it was deleted, we cannot use long-term backup retention. It seems like a bad point of design. I will report this issue and I believe this feature would be better in future.

You can also post your idea in [this Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response @Wayne, so since I cannot "un-delete" my deleted recovery services vault, would the only way to solve this is to be to restore my existing database to a new database and choose my new recovery vault from there?

Comment: HI, @FrankFu, I think the way you mentioned could not work. The vault is locked to the SQL Server , not database. So, If you want to still use another vault, I'm afraid that you need to create a new sql server and copy your database to the new server.

Comment: Right, thanks @Wayne! I really hope Microsoft will have a fix for this (or at least have better information around the consequences of deleting a vault)

Comment: Yeah, @FrankFu, I will report this issue. Also, if this answer is helpful to you, please mark it as answer, so that we can help more people.Thanks!